# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing with AngularJS Web App

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, rest, cors

I'm developing an AngularJS web app and I'm testing by running the app locally, e.g. it's not on a server. I keep running into the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).1 (unknown)

My SO research tells me this is an error on the server side, but I have been successful getting data back from my iOS app running in the simulator and have used Postman with success.

Per suggestion, I'm running the app through http-server.  Same issue.

I added a simple test case with the same results:

```
$http.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
.then(function (response) {
    alert("Search Results: " + response);
}, function(error) {
    alert("Could not get to Yahoo");
});
```

This is totally baffling.

Comment: What do you mean, "locally"? You need an http server to do ajax requests. if you're loading a page from a file:/// url, then you can't do ajax requests to servers

Comment: ^ you can't do async requests if you are having your browser render html from a direct file path. if you are running a local server using node / apache / python / etc. etc. then you can enable CORS headers on your local server, and you should then replicate this on your production server. Another important question here: are you developing with Angular 1 or Angular 2?

Comment: also, how is iOS coming in to play with your architecture? are you developing a Angular 2 + nativescript app? or an ionic + Angular 1 app? and if this is the case, what server are you trying to make async requests to and what is the environment of that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this comment:

> I'm developing an AngularJS web app and I'm testing by running the app locally, e.g. it's not on a server

Then the reason this is not working is obvious: You cannot make asynchronous calls to servers in Javascript with most modern browsers by default if you are not running the javascript from a webserver (http:// instead of file:///). This is a security measure that is built into virtually all browsers. You could possibly get around this by launching the browser with certain flags; for example with Chrome you could run from the command line `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files file:///[PATH_TO_FILE]`

However it's recommended that you just run the javascript from a web server. This is extremely simple to do, you could use the node package [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to serve the files up right from the directory they are in.

Comment: I found out how to disable CORS using a Chrome Extension, many thanks for answers.